# Gateway iP address after increasing network to /22

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, voip

I am using /24 network now but i need to increase to /22 (255.255.252.0) in order to get more space for upcoming VOIP users and mobile users. But all of our servers are configured from 192.168.1.1 to 1.30 with the gateway of 192.168.1.254.

I have some doubt that after changing to /22 (192.168.0. to 192.168.3.254) network on watchguard XTM 5 router, i want to maintain all the servers to same ip address so what will be the gateway address? Can i still use 192.168.1.254 for all 3 segment like below?

Servers and printers IP address : 192.168.1.1 to 1.250
Gateway address : 192.168.1.254 /22

Static VOIP users : 192.168.0.1 to 1.200
Gateway address : 192.168.1.254 /22

DHCP users : 192.168.2.1 to 1.252
Gateway address : 192.168.1.254 /22

showroom static users : 192.168.3.1 to 1.100
Gateway address : 192.168.1.254 /22

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Although the answer to your question is simple and was answered, I would have concerns as to the end result... You are making a large broadcast domain with multiple uses that could have implications on each other. This is an excellent scenario for VLANning the network... Create a VLAN for your VoIP users, one for the normal data network, and possible others depending on the applications of the other subnets (guest, mobile, WiFi, admin, etc). You would also want a solid QoS policy in place for a network of this size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any host address in a subnet can be used as the gateway address as long as you assign it to the router. The router is really just another host on the network.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Windows 8/10 application from the Windows Store "IP Calculator" you can get some useful information:

- Entered IP: 192.168.0.1/22

  - IP Subnet: 192.168.0.0/22
- First Host: 192.168.0.1

  - Last Host: 192.168.3.254
- Total Hosts: 1022
- IP Mask: 255.255.252.0
- Broadcast IP: 192.168.3.255
- ACL Bitmask: 0.0.3.255
- Class C Bits 1-3 = 110
- Parent Subnets:

  - 192.168.0.0/21
  - 192.168.0.0/20

Comment: Oh and, Ron is right (and answers your question directly), the gateway can be any routable address. Its just the path the packets will follow if their destination isn't local, so it can be anything routable and... of course, local :)